# IBM Datapower gatewayscript

Tags: gateway, ibm-datapower

I am trying to build a json that has 2 nodes, for example: "name":"david", and "id":"123123". So I am trying to do it with a new object with 2 nodes and then "stringify(obj)". I tried it in several ways but nothing is working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
const myObj = {
               name: "David", 
               id: "1"
           };
```

Or:

```
const myObj = {};
myObj.name = "David";
myObj.id = "1";
```

console.log(JSON.stringyfy(myObj);